# So i wrote a script and i need to fix it so it doesnt write in the script in string form, see the problem in its body

Tags: python, import

PyPython.py

```
from Project import *
v = open("Project.py", "w")
w = open("Backup.txt", "w")
PInput = None
DisableCode = "Save"
LineSeek = 0
Line = "None"
while PInput != DisableCode:
    PInput = input(": ")
    if PInput == "Create Line":
        Line = input("Type in the command: ")
        Line = repr(Line)
        v.write(Line + "\n")
        w.write(Line + "\n")
        print("Done!")
```

After running the code

in Project.py...

```
'print("Hi")'
```

It must be

print("Hi")

What should i do change in PyPython.py to get rid of string marks in Project.py?

Comment: So it should be command ```print('Hi')```

Comment: I don't know if there is a need for it but removing the line `Line = repr(Line)` and it might work.

Comment: ```repr()``` creates a printable form of the given object. Remove ```repr```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `repr(Line)` here. The repr() method returns a string containing a printable representation of an object.

Try removing that line, it will work as expected.

Comment: @TheHospi, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.